# Running, how many times a week? With what average speed? For how long?

Tags: running

I see advices that we shouldn't go to gym every day. But is it for everybody? or for the people that do serious stuff?  or if I just go run 1 mile in 13 minutes, do I still need to take a brake?
Does 1 mile even count? Or I should run at least 2 or 3 miles? Every day? 
I am 173lb and 5'8" tall and 31 years old male, So do I need to run more? faster?

And it is not for special events like 5K or marathon training, just to lose some weight, be healthy and get it shape.

Comment: You might need to clean up your question; it seems you're asking too many questions. Also, put emphasis on your goal; it got lost in the myriad of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your legs feel sore, I think it is ok to go without a break.

If your legs are sore, take a day break and catch up with rest :)

And no, that isn't really enough to see results. Rather going on distance, go on calories burnt, which your treadmill will tell you. Try to shoot at 300 calories minimum, and if you like mix it up with different machines such as elliptical, bike etc :)

But if you just want to run and increase calories burnt, you should turn incline to max, and run for longer/faster. If that's too intense, have a break when you normally do, for a few minutes, have drink etc., then try run another mile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while your muscles ache after training too much, your tendons, joints and bones will not. You won't notice that you're gradually working yourself into an injury, it will surprise you.

My guess is that we all should "rest" more than we think we should, but definitely not "rest" by sitting in a chair or lying on the sofa. Just not exercise as intensely.

And you probably don't have to run faster. A quote from Born to Run (said by running coach Ken Mierke):

> *Nearly all runners do their slow runs too fast*, and their fast runs too slow.

And, quoting Arthur Lydiard:

> Only go as fast as you can while holding a conversation.

---

This was in the news a few weeks ago (e.g. [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/larryhusten/2014/07/28/running-any-amount-is-good-and-more-may-not-be-better/)):

> Now a new study published in the Journal of the American College of Cardiology finds that even a small amount of exercise, even running for as little as 5 minutes a day, may be just as healthful as more exercise.

Comment: Kind of a mishmash of accurate and conjecture. The born to run is talking about easy runs versus hard runs in a full training regimen, not for the casual/recreational runner. Casual runners really have no reason to run fast at all. The Forbes link is to a study where the mortality and other factors drop markedly in limited (< 51 min) run program, but some of the higher time categories had lower risk than that. The "working yourself into an injury" is also pure guess, as there are many quite healthy people that exercise every day, some of whom have been doing it for many years.

Comment: @JohnP, an excellent comment! But I would still advise beginners to be careful, along these lines: "For some reason you can gain the fitness to run a solid 10 mile, or 15 mile effort before your body is ready for it if all you do to train your body is run." -- http://strengthrunning.com/2011/11/dont-let-your-engine-outpace-your-chassis-how-to-build-a-strong-body/